# Could I make an embedded program faster by statically linking it to the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, c, embedded, static-linking

This is probably a silly question, but is it possible to statically compile a C program along with an init system and the Linux kernel to make an embedded application? If so, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much what [unikernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel) are: an application linked with a “library operating system” to produce a single-purpose system. They don‘t have an init system because they only run a single application, and they don’t use Linux, rather systems designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was able to find (this)[https://research.redhat.com/blog/article/creating-a-linux-based-unikernel/] article so I'll read through it a bit more. If it solves the problem I'll edit my question to include the solution and I'll mark this as the right answer.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include an answer. Instead, post an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you're choosing a very difficult route to resolve what appears to be an xy problem.

There are very specific reasons why this is not how most software is produced. You mention one objective of making it go faster. If that is your only objective there are a lot of other things you should be trying first.

I think it would be significantly easier to re-implement your code as a kernel module - then you don't need to worry about entry points. context switches and libraries - but this is predicated on the notion that you need this as the exclusive process on the host.

Comment: I *was* planning to have only one application running on the host.

Comment: So start one program from init (using systemd seems overkill). You do know that your program will need to take care of setting up any network interfaces and mounting any additional filesystems after / ?

Comment: It's an installer, so it will have to do both of those things. I can use busybox or buildroot for this, but I was just wondering if this was possible because I think it would make the app a bit faster.

Comment: OMG no. It won't make the app faster. You would need to re-write large parts of the operating from scratch. It'll take a ridiculous amount of effort (years).

Comment: oh ._.  | but would it make the app *run* faster?

Comment: No. It wouldn't even *wait* faster. An installer is a classical example of something that does not get slowed down by the context switches, if programmed as userland program that asynchronously enqueued io operations.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok, thanks.